# Timing issue in C# services

Tags: c#, web-services, timing

I have a piece of code that calls a web service something like

`iResult = Proxy.Call(request, endpoint);`

I am facing the problem given below.

The service modifies the database. But it takes some time to reflect into database . During that amount of time my the execution flow moves ahead and I am left with old data and actual data reflects into database later. How can i tackle this situation.

Comment: Can you provide some code from ImportPendingUtilityBills method of web service?

Comment: I am assuming ImportPendingUtilityBills is running on a separate thread? can you call Thread.Join on that?

Comment: @Steve Yup it must be on a separate thread. Its running on a remote machine.

Comment: What type is `iResult`? If it is an `IAsyncResult` you could wait on that.

Comment: you need to be more specific. Do you have the control over ImportPendingUtilityBills thread? Can you block execution while waiting for ImportPendingUtilityBills? Do you need the UI to be responsive while the service is running? And is ImportPendingUtilityBills updating remote or local database? ect

Answer (score 0):

You need to make this call with await method.

just for reference on Await you can read following

[Understand Await and Async](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/asynchronous-programming-in-C-Sharp-5-0-part-1-understand-async/)

Comment: How await is going to tackle this?

Comment: @Puneet I can not call the web service using await. :( It is not designed like that.

Comment: @SarveshMishra you can have a look on the attached link.   Await make the execution to wait till the control returns, and this is what is needed to be done here.

Comment: @MadhurMaurya Than you might have to modifiy it else you can your thread sleep feature.

Comment: @PuneetGoel Await would wait until control returns, but according to question here, the method ImportPendingUtilityBills is returning before the update reflects in database. There could be something like fire and forget style async call in ImportPendingUtilityBills due to which the control returns.

Comment: @MadhurMaurya You can await ImportPendingUtilityBills if it is completely synchronous using Await Task.Run()

Comment: @SarveshMishra Tried the same. But still same problem. According to me service returns properly but it takes time to reflect changes in database. Since the the database used is also remote one.

Comment: @SarveshMishra is there a way to check that the transactions are commited or not in databse ?

Comment: @MadhurMaurya What is the type of iResult?

Comment: @PuneetGoel yes you are right here. What else should I try to fix it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105633/discussion-between-madhur-maurya-and-sarvesh-mishra).

Comment: @MadhurMaurya : i  am currently not available on chat as i am not at my machine. You can expand my solution and give it try. Later we can have discussion.